# Missing 0 when XOR bin values

Tags: python, xor, bin

I'm trying to XOR binary values but for some unknown reason I'm losing the first 0 in the conversion. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
m1 = int('01010100011001010111001101110100',2)
c1 = int('00111001000001000001000000000001',2)
c2 = int('00111101000100110000110000010001',2)

kk = bin(m1 ^ c1)[2:]
xx = int(kk,2)

m2 = bin(xx ^ c2)[2:]
print m2
```

For some reason this returns `1010000011100100110111101100100` instead of `01010000011100100110111101100100`, so I am losing the leading `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't know how many bits you want in the answer.  Tell it:

```
m2 = format(bin(xx ^ c2)[2:],'0>32')
```

The format string indicates a right-aligned, 32-character field padded with zeroes.

See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec).

In fact, you can just do the following with the `b` format specifier:

```
m1 = int('01010100011001010111001101110100',2)
c1 = int('00111001000001000001000000000001',2)
c2 = int('00111101000100110000110000010001',2)

print format(m1 ^ c1 ^ c2,'0>32b')
```

or alternatively:

```
print '{:0>32b}'.format(m1 ^ c1 ^ c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string method [zfill](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to pad the output to the number of digits you need.

```
m2 = bin(xx ^ c2)[2:].zfill(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros are generally stripped from all numbers.  For example, if you print the base 10 number 123, it doesn't print 0123 or 0000123.  It is the same with base 2 numbers.  If you were to print m1, c1, or c2, you would see that the leading zeros are not printed for them either.